# Writing SQL code with greater than and less than functions

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

WhenI try to run this code:

```
`SELECT 
CASE WHEN a.promotionflag=0 THEN 'NoPromotion' 
WHEN (Sales)/ISNULL(Margin,0) > -3.0000 
AND (Sales)/ISNULL(Funding, 0) < 0 THEN 'RED'
WHEN (Sales) <0 THEN 'RED'
WHEN (Sales)= 0 and (Margin) <0 then 'RED'
WHEN (Sales)/ISNULL(Margin, 0) >= 0 THEN 'GREEN'
WHEN (Sales) IS NULL THEN 'NonPriority'
WHEN (Margin) IS NULL THEN 'NonPriority'
ELSE 'YELLOW' 
END AS Promotions`
```

I receive an error that says "incorrect syntax near >" and brings me to the first instance where there is a >. Then when I hover about that, the first time I received the error it also mentioned a "boolean function."

I want this code to return me the color values based on the above criteria.

Comment: MySql does not use T-Sql - only Sybase and SQL Server use it. Please decide what database are you working with and edit the tags.

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` takes only one argument and returns 1 or 0 in MySQL. You are probably looking for `IFNULL`.
Also, using 0 as NULL replacement is a bad idea, as you'll get division by 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the standard `NULLIF()` function to prevent division by zero.  This version of the query should work:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN a.promotionflag = 0 THEN 'NoPromotion' 
             WHEN Sales/NULLIF(Margin, 0) > -3.0000 AND (Sales)/NULLIF(Funding, 0) < 0 THEN 'RED'
             WHEN Sales < 0 THEN 'RED'
             WHEN Sales = 0 and Margin < 0 THEN 'RED'
             WHEN Sales/NULLIF(Margin, 0) >= 0 THEN 'GREEN'
             WHEN Sales IS NULL THEN 'NonPriority'
             WHEN Margin IS NULL THEN 'NonPriority'
             ELSE 'YELLOW' 
       END) AS Promotions
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your query.  One possibility is a bad character around that position.  Sometimes just retyping the code can fix things.

Answer (score 0):

This one Change ISNULL TO IFNULL:

```
Set @promotionflag=-1;
set @Margin = 4.0000;
set @Sales = 3;
set @Funding = 4;
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @promotionflag=0 THEN 'NoPromotion' 
WHEN (@Sales)/(IFNULL(@Margin,0)) > -3.0000 AND (@Sales)/(IFNULL(@Funding, 0)) < 0 THEN 'RED'
WHEN (@Sales) <0 THEN 'RED'
WHEN (@Sales)= 0 and (@Margin) <0 then 'RED'
WHEN (@Sales)/(IFNULL(@Margin, 0)) >= 0 THEN 'GREEN'
WHEN (@Sales) IS NULL THEN 'NonPriority'
WHEN (@Margin) IS NULL THEN 'NonPriority'
ELSE 'YELLOW' 
END AS Promotions
```